# 3D plot not working, find max/min points

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, warning-messages, trigonometry, maximum

Im trying to plot this graph in mathematica:
(x+y)sin(x-y)

And this is my in- and output:

```
Plot3D[(x + y) (Sin[x - y]), {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}]
```

The output is this:
[image]

My goal is to find how many max/min and saddle points there are in R2 of the function. How can I get that answer from the graph?

Comment: Use `Sin` instead of `sin`.

Comment: Okay it's working now, but how can I determine how many max/min points there are?

Comment: I think you should first start by looking at a smaller segment of the plot then try to determine algebraically the min and max points.  Looks to me they are along the digaonal lines y=ax+b periodic in sin(x-y).

Comment: Change coordinates $u=x+y$, $v=x-y$, and optimize $u \sin v$, that is, solve $\sin v = 0,\ u \cos v = 0$, which is fairly easy by inspection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to see what is going on, a simpler example:

```
eq = {D[f[x, y], x] == 0, 
   D[f[x, y], y] == 0, -5 <= x <= 5, -5 <= y <= 5};
sol = Solve[eq, {x, y}] // N

Show[Plot3D[(x + y) (Sin[x - y]), {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
 , Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.03], Point[{x, y, f[x, y]} /. sol]}]]
```

[image]

We only have saddle points, no minima or maxima.

Now for the original problem: How many saddle points are in R^2?

```
f[x_, y_] = (x + y) Sin[x - y];
eq = {D[f[x, y], x] == 0, D[f[x, y], y] == 0};
Reduce[eq, {x, y}]
```

[image]

Therefore there are an infinity of saddle points on the diagonal x==-y and x== c1 Pi and x== (c1+1/2) Pi.